# A optimization problem with visual studio or a logic bug I cannot see?

Tags: .net, vb.net, math, game-physics

I have an small physics toy application I am developing. It works fine except the particles will not push each other away, only pull towards, I debugged that sub going through it command by command and realised the value 'H' would not change, what ever it was set to during the first pass through the sub is what it kept, the only way to change this value is to manually set it i.e 'h = 1'. Once the calculation is redone on the 'H' value it resets to what it was previously, even though the x1,y1,x2,y2 are all different, thus meaning H should be different.

I think it is me that has made a mathematical mistake somewhere, but I cannot see where it is. I need a fresh pair of eyes to look over my work. Please let me know if you find anything.

Thanks.

```
Public Sub movenodes()
    For i As Integer = 0 To connectionnumber
        If connections(i).exists = True Then
            Dim n1x As Integer
            Dim n2x As Integer
            Dim n1y As Integer
            Dim n2y As Integer
            Dim h As Integer
            n1x = nodes(connections(i).node1).x
            n2x = nodes(connections(i).node2).x
            n1y = nodes(connections(i).node1).y
            n2y = nodes(connections(i).node2).y
            h = 1
            h = Math.Sqrt(((nodes(connections(i).node1).x + nodes(connections(i).node2).x) ^ 2) + ((nodes(connections(i).node1).y + nodes(connections(i).node2).y) ^ 2))

            Me.Text = nodes(connections(i).node1).x & " " & nodes(connections(i).node1).y & " " & h
            If h > connections(i).happy Then
                If n1x > n2x Then
                    nodes(connections(i).node1).hspeed -= 0.1
                    nodes(connections(i).node2).hspeed += 0.1
                ElseIf n1x < n2x Then
                    nodes(connections(i).node1).hspeed += 0.1
                    nodes(connections(i).node2).hspeed -= 0.1
                End If
                If n1y > n2y Then
                    nodes(connections(i).node1).vspeed -= 0.1
                    nodes(connections(i).node2).vspeed += 0.1
                ElseIf n1y < n2y Then
                    nodes(connections(i).node1).vspeed += 0.1
                    nodes(connections(i).node2).vspeed -= 0.1
                End If

            ElseIf h < connections(i).happy Then
                MsgBox("")
                If n1x > n2x Then
                    nodes(connections(i).node1).hspeed += 0.5
                    nodes(connections(i).node2).hspeed -= 0.5
                ElseIf n1x < n2x Then
                    nodes(connections(i).node1).hspeed -= 0.5
                    nodes(connections(i).node2).hspeed += 0.5
                End If
                If n1y > n2y Then
                    nodes(connections(i).node1).vspeed += 0.5
                    nodes(connections(i).node2).vspeed -= 0.5
                ElseIf n1y < n2y Then
                    nodes(connections(i).node1).vspeed -= 0.5
                    nodes(connections(i).node2).vspeed += 0.5
                End If

            End If

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: "Once the calculation is redone on the 'H' value it resets to what it was previously, even though the x1,y1,x2,y2 are all different, thus meaning H should be different." - can you give a concrete example, with numbers, of where you get an `h` you didn't expect? Also, what are the types and magnitude of `hspeed` / `vspeed` - any chance this could be just rounding?

Answer (score 2):

Psychic debugging tells me you have `Option Strict Off`. I would urge you when using VB.NET to always have `Option Strict On`, unless you actually *need* the late binding functionality of `Off`. If you have `Option Strict On`, you will get

> error BC30512: Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Double' to 'Integer'

on that assignment of the result of `Math.Sqrt` to `h`. As @Marc Gravell alludes to, there is massive potential for a rounding issue here, since `h` is an `Integer`.